# Renjin/Java - Vector class to Java array class

Tags: java, renjin

I’m currently using `Ro.getElementAsDouble(index)` (code is below) to extract the values in `Ro` one by one into `LogNormArray` (`double[]`).  But I worry that a copy is wasting memory. I’m very much a newbie to java so apologies if I’m thinking about this incorrectly. In C I would copy a single address to "share" the data instead of coping the whole array. Is there an analogous pointer/address-passing workflow?

Toy Example I’m working with:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.script.*;
import org.renjin.sexp.*;
import org.renjin.script.*;

public class VectorRenjin {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double[] LogNormArray = new double[10];
    Vector Ro = LogNormalRand(10,0.0,1.0);
    System.out.println("draws from log-normal " + Ro);
    for(int i=0;i< Ro.length();i++) LogNormArray[i] = Ro.getElementAsDouble(i);
    System.out.println("draws from log-normal " + Arrays.toString(LogNormArray));
  }
  public static Vector LogNormalRand(int n,double a, double b) throws Exception{
    // create a script engine manager:
    RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine();
    engine.put("n",n);
    engine.put("a",a);
    engine.put("b",b);
    Vector res = (Vector)engine.eval("rlnorm(n,a,b)");
    return res;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a Vector result is not guaranteed to be backed by an array. For example, the statement `engine.eval("1:10000")` currently evaluates to an [IntSequence](http://javadoc.renjin.org/latest/org/renjin/primitives/sequence/IntSequence.html) instance. But this is an implementational detail subject to change.

The result of your evaluation above *will* always be an instance of `AtomicVector`, an interface implemented by all R values of type double, character, integer, complex, etc. The AtomicVector interface has a [toDoubleArray](http://javadoc.renjin.org/latest/org/renjin/sexp/AtomicVector.html#toDoubleArray()) method which will copy or create a double array containing the values.

`toDoubleArray()` does not return a reference to the array, even if the Vector is backed by an array, because Renjin Vector objects are meant to be immutable so they can be shared between threads.

Calling `toDoubleArray()` will probably still be more efficient than your code above because it only involves one virtual dispatch and many [implementations](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/blob/6089bb33fd70e56e4f15bfbf645814c25b968ca8/core/src/main/java/org/renjin/sexp/DoubleArrayVector.java#L171-L171) rely on Arrays.copyOf() which is faster than filling an array element-by-element.

If performance becomes a life-or-death matter, then you can check to see if the result of the evaluation is a DoubleArrayVector, and then call [toDoubleArrayUnsafe()](http://javadoc.renjin.org/latest/org/renjin/sexp/DoubleArrayVector.html#toDoubleArrayUnsafe()). But then you have to pinky-swear not to modify the contents.

Comment: Thanks and I'm really digging the Renjin project!